# How to save file to different server?

Tags: 8, files

I want to specify a different file system remote server path. So that if I upload a file then this should be served from different remote server. I am using Drupal version 8.

Comment: You have to write php stream wrapper(ie. form scratch or re-use some, and define it for drupal as available scheme).

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a custom [Stream Wrapper](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/file-api/writing-stream-wrappers), which provides read/write operations to your remote file system (those docs are for Drupal 7, but the concept, if not implementation, is identical).

Fortunately, for Drupal 8 someone's written a [stream_wrapper_example](https://www.drupal.org/node/2638290) module, which contains a lot of boilerplate code for re-use.

There are also a bunch of existing community-supplied stream wrapper modules, a Google search like "drupal stream wrapper modules" will list them all for you. Obviously whether or you can re-use any of those depends on exactly what you mean by "remote", and how you're implementing the connection.

Comment: This will be great start for a beginner and learn something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a NFS and configure the file system to this one.
No need to develop a streamWrapper with this method.